# Main program that calls GUI continues running before GUI is finished

Tags: java, oop, user-interface, initialization

The main method of my main program calls a `StartGUI` class which allows the user to make some selections, including `arrayX` and `arrayY`. The problem is that before the user is able to input into `MenuGUI`, the main program is already continuing to the next line, which requires `arrayX` and `arrayY` to have a value to initialize the array. I've provided an MCVE below:

```
public class Testing {

    // Public class variables
    public static int arrayX, arrayY, array[][];

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Start menu instance
        new StartGUI();

        // MenuGUI sets arrayX and arrayY
        array = new int[arrayX][arrayY];
        // More code here...
    }
}
```

How would I go about to make sure that `StartGUI` successfully sets the values of `arrayX` and `arrayY` before running the next line after that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would end the main method right after the `StartGUI()` call, then move everything else into a new method:

```
public class Testing {

    // Public class variables
    public static int arrayX, arrayY, array[][];

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Start menu instance
        new StartGUI();
    }

    public static void StartGUIFinished() {

        // MenuGUI sets arrayX and arrayY
        array = new int[arrayX][arrayY];
        // More code here...
    }
}
```

The `StartGUI` class would call the `StartGUIFinished()` method, and then proceed with the rest of the code.

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestion! So now `StartGUI()` will decide when to call the next method. Excellent idea!

Comment: You're welcome. If you have any additional questions, feel free to edit your question.